# Display intent delay

Tags: android

I have set an intent to open the dialer after 3 seconds, but I want to display the progress of the intent on the screen(as in time left) using a progress bar. Help, anybody?

```
final Handler handler = new Handler();
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
          @Override
          public void run() {
              Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
                intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:"));
                startActivity(intent); 
          }
        }, 3000); // 5 minutes delay before execute run()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this? Post a few Runnables sequentially, the last one actually executes the code.

```
final Handler handler = new Handler();
final ProgressBar bar = ...; // create and add a new progress bar and set max 3000

handler.postDelayed(new Runnable()
{
   int elapsed = 0;
   final int STEP_MS = 500;

    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        elapsed += 500;

        if (elapsed >= 3000)
        {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
            intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:"));
            startActivity(intent);
        }
        else
        {
            bar.setProgress(elapsed);
            handler.postDelayed(this, 500);
        }
     }
}, 500);
```